# Windows Phone 7.x / PhoneGap 2.4 - Readfile mix up resuld on multi read

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

I am converting my PhoneGap App that already is working on Android and iPhone, to work on windows Phone 7.x and 8.

I have a procedure that reads a number of XML files locally on the SDcard, and they seams to sometime the returning variable is not from the right file but from the previous read.

I have been trying all sort of things with Internal variables and calling functions with parameters but it just do not seam to work consistently.

Anyone have heard of this or have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, it looks like the call I did was invalid all along but PhoneGap accepted it.. But with 2.7 it was fixed..
I basically had some Inner Functions definitions that I "spread out" to separate functions and now it works.

So essentially you need 3 or 4 functions that async. call each others to read the file.. cumbersome but it works..

Thanks
Kim